# TikZ picture error: No node named n1 is known, inside a \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, foreach

I get the following error:

`! Package pgf Error: No shape named n1 is known.`

when I try to compile this code.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex',line width=0.7pt]

\foreach \i/\j in {0/1,1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,5/6,6/7,7/8}{%
\node (n\i) [draw,minimum size=1cm] at (1.7*\i,0){};
\ifthenelse{\i=7}{}{%
\draw[->] (n\i)--(n\j);}%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say `...n8 is known` instead of n1? Because there won't be a n8 node in any spin.

Comment: Yes, it says `n1` and, BTW, if I replace `\draw[->] (n\i)--(n\j)`  with `\draw[->] (n\i)--(n\i)` it gives no error. It reuses `\j`.

Comment: In the first iteration of the loop, you only create `n0`, but you already try to access `n1` as well. You'd need to add a nested `\ifthenelse` to check if you're in the first iteration, and do nothing if that's the case.

Comment: @Jake There is a `;` before the `\ifthenelse` line. This means that all nodes `n0` ... through `n7` are created

Comment: @Power_Project: No, the `;` is required to end the `\node ... ;` statement, the loop body is defined by the set of `{...}`. In every loop iteration, the `\node` line and the `\ifthenelse` statement are executed once.

Comment: That would have been correct if you had the draw statement in the true branch now it's on the false branch so executed in all

Answer (score 6):

You could (at least in this case) try a `chain`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex', ultra thick, 
  start chain, every join/.style=->, node distance=1.7]
\foreach \i in {0,...,8}
  \node (n\i) [draw, minimum size=1cm, on chain, join] {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would propose using a cleaner syntax. Here are two other ways;

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex',line width=0.7pt]
\node[draw,minimum size=1cm] (n0) at (0,0) {};
\foreach \x[remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0)] in {1,...,7}{%
\node(n\x) [draw,minimum size=1cm] at (1.7*\x,0){};
\draw[<-] (n\x) -- (n\lastx);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
% If feeling adventurous
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex',line width=0.7pt]
\node[draw,minimum size=1cm] (n0) at (0,0) {};
\foreach \x[remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0)] in {1,...,7}{%
\draw[<-]node[draw,minimum size=1cm,append after command=(n\x) -- (n\lastx)](n\x) at (1.7*\x,0){};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you are strictly using integers then you can get away with `\ifnum\i=7\else....\fi`

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Without breaking the `\foreach` statement, we could have done this in two ways:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',line width=0.7pt]
\foreach [evaluate=\i as \j using \i-1]\i in {0,...,7}{%
\node (n\i) [draw,minimum size=1cm] at (1.7*\i,0){};
\ifthenelse{\i=0}{}{%
\draw[->] (n\j)--(n\i);}%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',line width=0.7pt]
\foreach \i/\j in {0/-1,1/0,2/1,3/2,4/3,5/4,6/5,7/6}{%
\node (n\i) [draw,minimum size=1cm] at (1.7*\i,0){};
\ifthenelse{\i=0}{}{%
\draw[->] (n\j)--(n\i);}%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I agree with Jake's comment. You can accomplish this by separating the `\foreach` into two parts as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex',line width=0.7pt]

\foreach \i/\j in {0/1,1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,5/6,6/7,7/8}%
\node (n\i) [draw,minimum size=1cm] at (1.7*\i,0){};

\foreach \i/\j in {0/1,1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,5/6,6/7,7/8}{%
\ifthenelse{\i=7}{}{%
\draw[->] (n\i)--(n\j);}%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This should work correctly since all nodes `n0` ... through `n7` are surely created in the upper `\foreach` loop.

Comment: @AboAmmar This works fine and easy for me to understand, but can we just use the `\ifthenelse` statement without dividing the `foreach` statement?

Comment: @Power_Project Sure we can by intelligently fixing the values of the counters and the `\ifthenelse` condition. See my updated answer.